# Guard dog poops overnight on the garage/driveway

Tags: dogs, behavior, toilet-training, defecation

I live in a ranch (very small farm) in a tropical region, here there is 1000 m<sup>2</sup> (10 700 ft<sup>2</sup>) of grass for my guard dogs to poop, however they insist in pooping in front of the cars (or the rest of the cemented area) during the night, close to a sheltered area where their dog bed is. During the day they poop on the grass and I give them treats and praise, if I see them defecating on the cement I just firmly say "no" and wait a few minutes when they are playing elsewhere and clean it up. I have tried:

- veterinarian cleaning products
- a repelling spray
- designating this as their feeding area (after cleaning it properly)

however, every morning they have pooped almost on the same place. Is there anything else I can do to teach them not to poop on the cement without being awake 24/7?

Most advice I read recommends fencing them within the area I want them to poop, however because of the house design and their function guarding the terrain this is extremely impractical and very very expensive here.

Notes:

- They are not allowed inside the house, but receive plenty of attention during the day and have their "own house".

Comment: One of our dog experts may know a solution for this, but to me it sounds like your dogs sleep, wake up and urgently need to go. At night after waking up there is not time to go further so the drive way is where they do their business. I think this might be the case especially since they go the right place during the day.